# OnEdit doesn't get called

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am using jQuery `.editable()` to make a `<p>` editable.

What I am trying to do is to select the text already in the element when a user clicks on it to edit.

I've read that `OnEdit` is the option that I should use to call a function every time a user clicks on an .editable object, but for some reason my test `alert()` isn't being called at all.

JS:

```
 this.$('.name').editable(function (value, settings) {
        if (value.length > 50)
            value = value.substr(0, 50);
        that.model.save("name", value);
        return(value);
    }, HotelNinjas.Settings.textPluginData);
    this.showRoomType();
    return this;
},
...

onEdit: function (e) {
    alert("edit"); // <<--- DOESN'T GET CALLED
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<p class="name">Some Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post a bit more code, or even better, create a jsFiddle. In any case, try using this instead for alerting on edit.

```
$('.name').on('edit',function (e) {
    alert("edit");
});
```

Does your javascript console output any errors by chance?